# JodReports Alternatives

Tags: java, frameworks, reporting, report

What are the best alternatives for JodReports library ??

Comment: just wondering, what's wrong with jodreports?

Comment: No wrong with it, I am just developing something similar to it, I am using it at anyway in three of my projects, I want to compare existing technologies doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [XDocReport](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/).

It's very well documented and even has a couple of features that JODReports doesn't (the two are briefly compared in the XDocReport [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/FAQ)).

Answer (score 1):

There's [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which has templating facilities and is based on similar technologies.